Physics applied to coin doesn't work well
As you can notice in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPglJKEgFyI, I just want to throw a bunch of coins from above but it's not working fine. When they hit the floor, they never stop moving. What parameters should I change? the ones I have set are:
For the floor:

Type: Passive
Shape: Convex Hull
Friction: 0.2
Bounciness: 0

For each coin:

Type: Active
Shape: Convex Hull
Mass: 0.0075 kg
Friction: 0.2
Bounciness: 0.2
✅ Deactivation


Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Hello, try to scale up your coin and don't forget to apply the scale, or try another Collisions > Shape, for example Cylindier. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
